Smallest ellipsoid containing unit ball sliced at hyperplane
I was trying to understand the ellipsoid algorithm and I was reading theorem B.1 on this survay on the ellipse algorithm which if I understand correctly gives the minimum volume of the ellipsoid containing the unit ball after we sliced it with the plane at $x_1=\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a real number. It seems to me it would make sense to find the volume of the remaining part of the ball after slicing at $x_1=\alpha$ for $-1<\alpha<1$.
However, in the theorem, they consider $-1/n <\alpha <1$? and not $-1<\alpha<1$. Is there no ellipse containing the rest of the ball if we cut the ball at planes such that $-1<x_1<-1/n$?
